# Why might Mr. Bingley "leave the next generation to purchase" in "Pride and Prejudice"?

Tags: meaning, jane-austen, pride-and-prejudice

From *Pride and Prejudice* by Jane Austen (volume 1, chapter 4):

> Mr. Bingley inherited property to the amount of nearly a
>   hundred thousand pounds from his father, who had intended to
>   purchase an estate, but did not live to do it.  Mr. Bingley
>   intended it likewise, and sometimes made choice of his county;
>   but as he was now provided with a good house and the liberty of
>   a manor, it was doubtful to many of those who best knew the
>   easiness of his temper, whether he might not spend the
>   remainder of his days at Netherfield, and leave the next
>   generation to purchase.

What does this paragraph mean?

Answer (score 5):

It means that that Mr. Bingley was content with renting Netherfield and probably never would get around to buying a house of his own. In other words, he would leave the purchase of a house to the next generation, just like his father.

Answer (score 0):

The *respectable* thing to do was to buy land, and live off the income from it.  Even a professional job was a less prestigious way to live, and as for manufacturing -- forget it.

Consequently, his father intended to buy land, to make his family more respectable.  Mr. Bingley intends the same, but his easy-going nature would make it less likely.

(Part of this would entail buying a country house, but the lands were the vital part.)